# robocopy retain files in destination directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, robocopy

Is there a way to retain files/directories in the destination directory while still Mirroring the source directory

```
Source ---
    A.txt
    B.txt
Destination ---
    Z.txt
```

Run robocopy

```
Destination ---
   A.txt
   B.txt
   Z.txt
```

Comment: your example is what you want, or what happen when you run robocopy?

Comment: @yagmoth555 my example is what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to **not** use any options that include or imply the `/purge` flag 
(notably `/mir`).  Just use `/e`

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx#Mirror_directory_excl_deletion

Server 2012, 2016 docs:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy#BKMK_remarks